# White spaces appear around the document to preview

Tags: wpf, printing, system.printing, documentpaginator

I have WPF Application which use printing.
I have class inherite from "DocumentPaginator"

```
class ReportPaginator : DocumentPaginator
{
    private Size pageSize;

    public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override bool IsPageCountValid
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override int PageCount
    {
        get { return pageCount; }
    }

    public override Size PageSize
    {
        get { return pageSize; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                pageSize = value;
                CalculatesPage();
            }
        }
    }

    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
       // some code.
    }  
}
```

When I get FixedDocumentSequence from this paginator to preview the document before printing.
the "pageSize" property did NOT applied for this DocumentPage, and there is white spaces around the pages
How can I solve this problem

Comment: Are you sure the document itself does not have space?  See  PagePadding

Comment: where can I locate the PagePadding property ?

Comment: Did you you try msdn and search on PagePadding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the case if some one had the same problem of this. 
My problem was in the my own code [specifically the part that generate the Page in the `GetPage()` method], I was generating white spaces around the page itself when implement `GetPage` method.

if you are having same problem, may be double-checking `GetPage` method may be helpful.

Comment: It is good that you solved your problem, but you should put an answer that will help others if they have the same problem. “double-checking your code” does not do that.

Comment: I solved this from long time, I really hope to write the code which  solved my problem, and you are right 100%, this could be more useful for other.